# jQuery - Childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how to change a specific child of an element. In this case I want to change the first a of ul. I tried this:

[HTML AND JQUERY]

```
<body>

<ul id="nav">
    <a href="#"><li>1</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>2</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>3</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>4</li></a>      
    <a href="#"><li>5</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>6</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>7</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>8</li></a>
</ul>

<div id="hidden">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <img src="#">
</div>

<script>
    var main = function() {
    var el1H1 = "Text";
    var el1P = "Some text again.";
        $('ul').child().click(function() {
            $('#hidden').slideDown(1000);       
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(main);
</script>
```

Comment: Invalid HTML. `ul` can only have `li` as child, You need to change your HTML like `<li><a href="#">1</a></li>`

Comment: @Satpal I needed to do that to get the full height background change while hovering.

Comment: There are several problems with your example. Perhaps if you clarify the overall aim you will get better results here :)

Comment: And we're telling you it can't be done, it's invalid and the browser moves the anchors for you as they can't be where you've placed them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li>
     <a></a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a></a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a></a>
   </li>
</ul>

$('#nav li:first-child').find('a').click(function() {
        $('#hidden').slideDown(1000);       
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. But if I change the <li> and <a> to eachother's places, then my <li> isn't the same height as my navigation bar anymore. And my hovering and link effect is gone then...

Comment: @HydraCles if you want to keep your html structure then you can use this: `$('#nav a:first-child').click(function() {
        $('#hidden').slideDown(1000);       
});`

Comment: @HydraCles: You don't fix other styling issues by using broken HTML to avoid them! You need to instead fix your height issue, or at least do not use a UL as the parent of anchors.

Comment: @erkaner Ah, thank you :). I could just use the CSS selector between the '___'. Didn't know :o. I'll 'SOLVED' you as soon as possible: 3 min.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Can I also use just <li>s without a <ul> / <ol>. Is that broken HTML?

Comment: @HydraCles: That is broken too. LIs must be under a UL.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Fixed. With <span> instead of <li>.